# exaile 3.4.5 shows file=sys.stderr error on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python, music, exaile

I installed exaile from tar ball.

Exaile ver: 3.4.5
OS : ubuntu 16.04

Its not launching the app while click on icon. I executed `exaile` command in terminal and it shows the below error.

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 182
file=sys.stderr)
    ^
```

Comment: So, what are lines 180-185 of `/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py`, a file used for site-local python3.5 customizations. Have you (or your system manager) changed this file?

Comment: i didnt changed any python stock files

Comment: Is that the full traceback?

Comment: yes.I got only the above error.

Answer (score 0):

As answered in [Getting a syntax error when I type pthon on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159614/getting-a-syntax-error-when-i-type-pthon-on-ubuntu-18-04), the issue is likely due to one application (`exaile` here) expecting python 2, and you having python 3 as the default.

In particular, check `sys.path`. It likely points to python 3.5, i.e., it includes `/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py`.
As per [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path), `sys.path` is a list built from `PYTHONPATH` and other installation-dependent paths.

As a quick check, find if you have any python 2 in your system (`$ python2 --version`).
If so, find where is the corresponding `site.py` located, most likely `/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py`.
Then,

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py
$ exaile
```

If this works, then for a definitive setup you would have to find a way to change your `sys.path` when executing `exaile`.

There are quite a few options, depending if you launch it via command line or a launcher. For instance, you could write a script that exports with `export PYTHONPATH="/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py:${PATH}"` and then executes whatever you need. That can also be the target of your launcher.

PS: Note also [the best way to add to `PYTHONPATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/415028/137608)