# Getting a syntax error when I type pthon on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, python

When I type echo $PYTHONPATH I get

```
/usr/lib/python3.6
```

But when I type python as user root I get

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 183
file=sys.stderr)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the reason for this error ?

When I type python3.6 I get no errors. If this question needs to be moved to UNIX SE please let me know.

Comment: AFAIK, the default `python` on Ubuntu 18.04 is still `python2.7` - the error suggests you're executing `python2` with a `PYTHONPATH` that's only appropriate for `python3`

Comment: @steeldriver  Thanks for your response. How can I fix the problem ?

Comment: That depends - what are you trying to do? why (and how) did you set your `PYTHONPATH` as  `/usr/lib/python3.6`?

Comment: @steeldriver I guess I do not have to set it. If I unset the PYTHONPATH will the error go away ?

Comment: I expect so ...

Comment: @steeldriver That works ! Do you want to answer and have me accept ?

Comment: `/usr/lib/python3.6` is already in `sys.path` for `python3`, so I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish

Comment: @wjandrea Few weeks back I was trying to build a software that required me to do it. I can't remember what it is now but I have removed it.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/829458/exaile-3-4-5-shows-file-sys-stderr-error-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is consistent with trying to run the `python3.6/site.py` file using `python2.7`:

```
$ python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.6/site.py
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 183
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Since `python2.7` is still the default for Ubuntu 18.04, you should avoid setting your `PYTHONPATH` to a python3-specific value.

Comment: This worked for me in a case where `bzr` under msys2 was giving this error. I guessed `bzr` was based on python 2, so I changed `PYTHONPATH` from `lib/python3.8/site-packages` to `lib/python2.7/site-packages` to fix the error (these dirs are not under `/usr` in msys2, but otherwise the issue is the same).